# Validation Rule having syntax error

Tags: validation-rule

My below validation rule is showing syntax error as " missing " )", I checked throughly but couldn't able to figure out where exactly I went wrong or missed the bracket or comma, can anyone please help me out.

```
OR
( 
AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.1), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 2" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.2), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 5" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.3), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 6" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.3, 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 7" 
)
)
```

Comment: If you have troubles when editing formulas, don't hesitate to paste it in a text editor like Notepad++. It highlights the parentheses.

Comment: This validation rule **doesn't make sense AT ALL** as it will let any user to bypass it, for most cases if not all.

Comment: May i know plz how can it bypass ? as the role been assigned to the specific user and only those with the role can change it. Although till now its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the last 0.3 you forgot a )

```
OR
( 
AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.1), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 2" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.2), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 5" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)>0.3), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 6" 
), 

AND( 
OR(ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.05, ABS(Premium_adjustment__c)<0.3), 
ISCHANGED(Adjusted_technical_premium__c), 
$User.UserRoleId<>"UW 7" 
)
)
```